# Scroll-behavior: smooth Not Working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm in the process of creating a single page site that relies on the `scroll-behavior:smooth` CSS property and the method .`scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'})`. I use these mainly to provide a smooth transition between sections, not critical but aesthetically pleasing. Suddenly this feature doesn't seem to be working in Google Chrome. I tested out on Firefox and Chrome mobile and in these works.

I made this pen with the basics of my page: https://codepen.io/gabriel-ar/pen/rEjdYb

Temporarily I've been using https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll , and it solves `scrollIntoView`, but other plugins like [PhotoSwipe](https://photoswipe.com/) are not handling transitions well.

- Therefore, what is the best fix here? `smoothscroll` solves part of it, but apparently not everything.
- Is this a bug in Chrome?
- `scroll-behavior:smooth` doesn't seem to be the only property affected, what other thing could have stopped working, if any?

**Google Chrome Version 106.0.5249.119**

I already uninstalled Chrome and reinstalled it. I Also ran a clean install on a sandbox with the same results.

Thank you!

### Update & Solution

It seems this is a local issue, just happening on my computer. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Cannot reproduce on v 106.0.5249.119

Comment: Smooth scrolling might be disabled at the OS level. For example, in Windows 10, press Win+U to open Ease of Access and make sure the "Show animations in Windows" setting is turned on. In macOS, it's apparently under Accessibility > Display > Reduce Motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue some time ago, and I came up with this solution:

1. Open new tab
2. Go to Chrome's Experimental Flags (chrome://flags)
3. Search for `'smooth scrolling'`
4. Set the flag to `enabled`

Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: I does work! Now, that works just for me, but not for the final users :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue on Chrome version 106.0.5249.119, so it might be only on your local machine.

Comment: yes, it could be, I'm going to check my drivers and try on a separate laptop. Thank you everyone.

Comment: You're welcome! I think the question can be closed now :)

Comment: Indeed, this may be happening just on my computer, even inside the sandbox.